# What Twitter API returns status and its replies?

Tags: twitter

I am looking at [Twitter API reference](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index) but I cannot seem to find the right API to get a tweet and its replies that would be equivalent to what I can see on the Twitter web site of given status itself.

What Twitter API returns status and its replies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API endpoint that returns all the replies of an individual Tweet. You'd need to use the search API to find them.

Comment: I do not even need all replies. Just what is seen on the web page.